# How to use pipeline method in django using library social-auth-app-django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I create an django project name is registration in this project I build an app name is mainApp so in this project I have to create sign in with google functionallity so this I have done it now I want this sign with google email-id is stored in my created custom model table So how can I do this

I try it for the pipeline method but when I click on login with google it takes only reload not signin within the home page